# "Говорящая орфография"

Tags: орфография, реформа

SCRIBITUR AD NARRANDUM, NON AD PROBANDUM (пишу для того, чтобы рассказать, а не для того, чтобы доказать)

1. Я хочу еще раз обсудить тему, связанную  с рассказом Паустовского. Мнение наших экспертов мне уже известно, но сейчас мне хотелось бы  ПОДЕЛИТЬСЯ  СВОИМИ ВПЕЧАТЛЕНИЯМИ с ТВОРЧЕСКИМИ ЛЮДЬМИ – с теми, кто  не проверяет текст, а создает его.
2. Речь идет о предложении  «ЛОСЬ ШЕЛ СКАЧКАМИ В СТОРОНУ ОЗЕР, ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ СПЕШИЛ НА ВОДОПОЙ».  Когда я начинала  анализировать это предложение, у меня не было  текста рассказа. Форма БСП (с тире) казалась очень логичной – она снимала все вопросы по семантике и по пунктуационному оформлению предложения.  И  уж конечно этот вариант не был новым, он широко используется, например: «Собака исчезла, – наверное, ее кто-то украл». «Он не приводит никаких фактов, – очевидно, это всё только слухи».
3. Реакция форума меня несколько удивляет,  и вот я беру  текст рассказа.  И ясно вижу, что мой вариант ТУДА НЕ ПОДХОДИТ. И  не менее ясно вижу, что в виде отдельного предложения он меня устраивает по-прежнему. Просто волшебство какое-то! Читаю еще внимательнее – и  понимаю, в чем дело. Я считала, что автор описывает РЕАЛЬНОЕ СОБЫТИЕ (Лось шел скачками в сторону озер – должно быть, спешил на водопой), а он изображает РЕКОНСТРУКЦИЮ ЭТОГО СОБЫТИЯ (Лось шел скачками в сторону озер, должно быть спешил на водопой).   Мы НЕ ВИДИМ животное, а ПРЕДПОЛАГАЕМ, как все происходило,  – то  есть  здесь как бы два раза «должно быть». Я считаю это предложение УНИКАЛЬНЫМ  АВТОРСКИМ РЕШЕНИЕМ,  и именно  авторское графическое оформление надо обязательно сохранить.
4. Но то, что происходит дальше, меня не очень устраивает.  Теперь  этот вариант  в «новой орфографии»   дается как единственный, да еще  в качестве абстрактного примера к общему правилу.  Какое там авторство, какие там виртуальные и реальные события – только так, и не иначе!
5. Правила 1956 года – очень тонкая книжечка, пунктуация там дается на 50 страницах. Академики предлагают  нам ИДЕИ, хотя они и имеют форму конкретных решений.  За  50 последующих лет  эти принципиальные решения  применялись к  различным конкретным случаям и приняли форму БЕСКОНЕЧНОГО КОЛИЧЕСТВА ПРАВИЛ,  которые  именно в силу своей многочисленности ПЕРЕСТАЛИ РАБОТАТЬ. Орфографическая машина забуксовала, потребовалось  ее упрощение.
6. Поэтому лучше бы нам вернуться к идеям, которые дают  СВОБОДУ ТВОРЧЕСТВА. В нашем случае Правила 1956 года позволяют использовать вводное слово в качестве присоединительных союзов там, где МЫ СЧИТАЕМ  ЭТО НУЖНЫМ, в то время как НОВАЯ АВТОРИТАРНАЯ ОРФОГРАФИЯ ДИКТУЕТ НАМ ЖЕСТКИЕ И ОДНОЗНАЧНЫЕ (ХОТЯ И УПРОЩЕННЫЕ) РЕШЕНИЯ. И не удивительно, что многие люди и в течение долгого времени  (возможно, чисто интуитивно) сопротивляются реформе.

Comment: Ваша идея о двух редакциях Правил мне очень  по душе - нестандартное и, по-моему, очень верное решение. В конце концов, лингвистику можно сравнить с математикой, которую  делят на элементарную и высшую, да и все другие науки имеют разные ступени сложности. Только орфографические правила одни и те же и для школьников, и для литературных редакторов, и для писателей. В результате школьники не знают даже основ, а писатели, скованные формальными правилами, не могут нормально работать.

Comment: При этом надо хорошо понимать: у нас должна быть ОДНА СИСТЕМА ПРАВОПИСАНИЯ, НО РАЗНЫЕ УРОВНИ ЕЕ ОПИСАНИЯ в соответствии с разной сложностью текстов.

Comment: София, что Вы называете "новой орфографией" (см. п. 4) и "НОВОЙ АВТОРИТАРНОЙ ОРФОГРАФИЕЙ" (см. п. 6)?

Comment: После 1956 года было сделано несколько попыток проведения   реформы, орфографические комиссии работали в 1964, 1973 и 2001 годах. Их целью являлось  упрощение и унификация русского письма. Однако всех случаях противников реформ оказалось больше, чем сторонников. Последняя реформа 2001 года была официально отклонена, но она в Правилах орфографии Лопатина  продолжается не в открытую, негласно, не очень заметно. А направление одно: унифицировать, упростить, сделать одинаковым и обязательным.

Comment: А тема, которая здесь разбирается, тому наглядный пример. Была идея: вводные слова могут играть роль присоединительных союзов и ПОКАЗАНО это  на примере уточняющих членов предложения. А можно ли их применить к другим обособленным членам? Иногда - можно, иногда - нет. Но вводится правило - всегда нужно! Не очень хорошее правило, но можно как-то смириться. А в Правилах Лопатина идем еще дальше: теперь это  "всегда нужно" и для однородных членов, и в сложных предложениях.

Comment: Как меняется смысл и интонация - это никого не волнует. Получается, что мы ломаем систему русского письма, потому что не можем обучить школьников.

Comment: София, согласны ли Вы с тем, что Союз Советских Социалистических Республик был ликвидирован ещё и потому, что "советский народ" заблокировал реформирование правил русской орфографии и русского правописания после 1956 года (выражение в кавычках позаимствовано из преамбулы последней конституции СССР)?

Comment: СССР распался  потому,  что  стал  не  нужен  руководству.  А  про  то,  что  советский  народ  что-то  такое  заблокировал,  я  не  слышал.  Расскажите  или  ссылочку  дайте.

Answer (score 1):

Применение  правил  ОиП  зависит  даже  не  от  сложности,  а  от  назначения  текста -  в  юридических  и  научных  текстах  разночтения  нежелательны,  если  не  сказать  недопустимы,  а  художественной  прозе  и,  особенно,  поэзии  возможны,  а  может  даже  желательны   такие  разночтения,  расширения  смысла  образов,  передача  не  только  смысла,  но  и  ауры  речи.  В  этом  случае  унификация,  упрощение  правил  будет  только  разрушать  художественную  ткань   текста.  Но  школьная  грамматика  должна  быть  проще  (  имеется  в  виду  пунктуация  ).  Видимо  не  так  легко  провести  границу  между  уровнями  на  практике.  Школьникам  ведь  ещё  и  оценки  ставят.  Но  сама  идея  о  базовом  и  расширенном  уровне  знании  правил  ОиП  мне  нравится.